# Move a listview Up/Down a form using the scrollbar of the Form VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, treeview, scrollbar, move

My Form contains a Treeview, I would like for the treeview to move up and down the form with the scrollbar.

Here is a screenshot of the form.
The TreeView can be seen on the left hand side

I don't have any sample code regarding this as I am not sure where to begin

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thank You

[image: The TreeView can be seen on the left hand side]

Comment: I didnt get your question, why do you need to do that? As far as I know the `treeview` will make a `scroll bar` everytime the data bounces off the size of the `treeview` do you mean that you have controls also on the bottom of the `form`? so thats why it has a `scrollbar` and your asking to move the data inside the `treeview` based on forms `scrollbar`

Comment: Yes you are right the treeview will make a scroll bar everytime the data bounces off the size. However I require the whole treeview to move down with the scroll as there are more controls towards the bottom. Thank you

Comment: Wow my guess is correct, I try to figure it out. BRB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research on the topic and found myself a solution.
Just gonna leave it here for anyone else with the same question.

```
'======================================
'TreeView Location Change with Scroll

Private Sub Form2_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Scroll
    'Gets the vertical scroll values as an Integer
    Dim verticalscroll As Integer = AutoScrollPosition.Y * -1
    'Moves the Treeview to new location
    EstimTree.Location = New Point(5, verticalscroll)

    'If statement to contain the treeview within my form       
    If EstimTree.Location.Y <= 130 Then
        EstimTree.Location = New Point(5, 130)
    End If
End Sub
```